# How to automatically Click a Button in Android once time?

Tags: android

I have one button , click that button will show info , but I don't want to click it by myself , I hope it can be automatically running in first time.
maybe 0.1 seconds after ? it's possible ? Thanks.

Edit : 
Thanks All. I have already solution.

Comment: Yes. What you tried so far ?

Comment: just put code in one method and call that method in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call button's perfomClick() method and set button onClickListener on your activity for button and set following code on your activity's onCreate method.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); Button btnYourButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnYourButton);
    //TODO Number Of Second You Want Delay.
    int noOfSecond = 1;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Set your button auto perform click.
            btnYourButton.performClick();
        }
    }, noOfSecond * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Handler and a delayed `Runnable`  to be executed on the UI thread after 1 seconds

to perform automatically of button use `performClick();`

```
public boolean performClick ()
```

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound

using below code you can automatically Click a Button after one second

**add this sample code in your onCreate()**

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           btnOk.performClick();
        }
    }, 1000);
```